# Skip geocoding in some cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I'm using the Geocode gem in order to convert addresses to (logitude, latitude) coordinates. In order to do so, I added this in the user Profile model that is geocoded:

```
geocoded_by :address

after_validation :geocode, if: Proc.new { |p| p.address_changed? }
```

This works great, but now, I'm making a migration script that populate the Profiles table with addresses, and also longitudes and latitudes. In this case, geocoder is still doing the conversion, and I get the following warning many times:

```
Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.
```

How can I skip the geocoding in some cases, like in migration when I already have coordinates?

Comment: Thanks @rene. I'll take this in my next posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/initializers/geocoder.rb` put the following code:

```
Geocoder::Configuration.lookup = :yandex

for update to quota: 25000 requests / day
```

More details [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#yandex-yandex).

Answer (score 1):

The right answer depends on how you implemented `address_changed?`.

The recommended is:

```
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
```

but I tend to use:

```
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and !obj.address.latitude? and !obj.address.longitude? }
```

in which case you will skip the geocoding if a `latitude,longitude` pair has already been set.